# Windows Powershell Basic Questions - new user

Tags: powershell

When trying to open a file with text editor VIM, I am unable to open the file unless VIM (shortcut) is in my current working directory. As an example, I am able to write `start firefox` to open a firefox window. However, `start vim C:\filepath\filename.txt` does not work unless a vim shortcut is in my current directory. How do I get around this?

Also, is there a way to have a program execute a file in the current working directory without having to reference the entire file path? For example instead of `Start-Process vim C:\Users\User\Desktop\File\file.txt` is there an available path shortcut like `Start-Process vim ~\file.txt` with `~` representing the current working directory?

Comment: Yes. You can use `file.txt` directly.  You can also precede it by a dot and a backslash. `.\file.txt` (forward slash path work also). If you need to change the working directory, you can use `Set-Location`

Comment: As for Vim vs Firefox, firefox can be started without specifying the full path because its full path is already present in the Path environment variable. If Vim is not there, you'll need to do that first before calling it without it's path. The other alternative, which does not require to modify PATH variable, is to put the exe path in a variable first, such as this `$Vim = "c:\Path\To\Vim.exe"` then invoking the line later on when you want to call it `& $vim "file.txt"`.

Comment: @SagePourpre Thank you. Editing the PATH variable solved issue 1 and your response solved issue 2.

Comment: @SagePourpre I would like to give you credit but it is not allowing me to clear the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS need to determine the full path of the exe, no matter what.

There's 2 ways that it will happen.

- You're calling the executable from it's working directory
- The executable location is in the Windows environment variable.

You can view the PATH variable content through this simple statement

```
$env:Path -split ';' | sort
```

You sill see that the Firefox path is listed there, but not the one from VIM.
That's why the former can be started by it's executable name and the latter require the full path.

You need to add VIM directory to your PATH variable if you want to be able to call it just by typing `vim`

Otherwise, if you have restricted access or don't want to edit that variable, you can also set a `$vim` variable, then invoke it whenever you want to call the executable.

Regarding the second part of your question

- Powershell use the dot as a reference to the current directory `.\file.txt`.
- You can also just specify the filename without anything else `file.txt`.
- Both backslash `\` & slash `/` work for filepath so `.\file.txt` and `./file.txt` are both valid ways to reference the file.
- Use `..\` to reference the parent directory (e.g. `..\file.txt`)

```
$Vim = "c:\Path\To\Vim.exe"

& $vim "file.txt"
& $vim ".\file.txt"
#Forward slash also work for paths
& $vim "./file.txt"
```